# Translation of "I would be lying if I said that ..."

Tags: translation, english-to-german, subjunctive

> I would be lying if I said that I'm not stressed about the upcoming test.

How can this be translated into German?

> Ich würde lügen, wenn ich sagen würde, dass ich über die kommende Prüfung nicht gestresst bin.

Is the part "Ich würde lügen" correct? I'm not sure if it properly reflects the meaning of "I would be lying".

Comment: Your translation is correct. But it's "wegen der kommenden Prüfung" instead of "über die kommende Prüfung".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly more often you may hear this put into the following expression:

> [Es wäre gelogen, wenn ich sagen würde...](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22es%20w%C3%A4re%20gelogen%20wenn%20ich%20sagen%20w%C3%BCrde%22)

but

> [Ich würde lügen, wenn ich sagen würde...](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22ich%20w%C3%BCrde%20l%C3%BCgen%20wenn%20ich%20sagen%20w%C3%BCrde%22)

is a correct translation, and it is also being used.

On a higher level (where people may not even remotely want to be put under suspect of being a liar) you may also say

> [Es wäre vermessen[,] zu behaupten...](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22es%20w%C3%A4re%20vermessen%20zu%20behaupten%22)

Answer (score 2):

"Ich würde lügen" kann man ohne Weiteres sagen (und schreiben). Um die Aussage zu verstärken, ist es besser, statt "sagen" "behaupten" zu verwenden:

> Ich würde lügen, würde ich behaupten, dass mich die kommende Prüfung
>   nicht stresst.

In einer schon übertragenen, elliptischen Konstruktion könnte man auch sagen:

> Ich müsste lügen auf die Frage, ob mich die kommende Prüfung nicht
>   stresst.

Comment: Ich finde Zweiteres klingt um Größenordnungen natürlicher als Ersteres, zumindest in gesprochenem Deutsch.